# Maximum retries and retry interval for Kafka JDBC Sink Connector when a database is down

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to test and evaluate the behavior of a Kafka JDBC Sink Connector when the database is down.

When a new message is received in Kafka while the database is down, the following error is reported:

```
INFO Unable to connect to database on attempt 1/3. Will retry in 10000 ms. (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:91)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to access availability database 'Giorgos' because the database replica is not in the PRIMARY or SECONDARY role. Connections to an availability database is permitted only when the database replica is in the PRIMARY or SECONDARY role. Try the operation again later.
```

And after some retries, the following error will be reported and the task will be killed:

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-giorgos_test-2} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:173)
```

Where can I modify the number of retires and the retry interval which according to the first error is set to `10000` ms?

Say I want for the worker to keep trying to connect to the database for 5 minutes. Which parameters should I configure to do so?

**EDIT to include required files:**

sink-file.properties

```
name=sink-test
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=GIORGOS.TOPIC
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://ip:port;DatabaseName=Streaming;user=myuser;password=mypass
auto.create=true

# DB failover
max.retries=10
retry.backoff.ms=10000

pk.mode=record_value
pk.fields=ID
insert.mode=upsert
transforms=ExtractField
transforms.ExtractField.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value
transforms.ExtractField.field=data
```

worker.properties (I have multiple files as I am running in distributed mode)

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
group.id=connect-cluster

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081



config.storage.topic=connect-configs
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
status.storage.topic=connect-statuses
config.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1



internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

rest.port=8040
rest.advertised.port=8040

plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

Answer (score 3):

As explain here : https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_config_options.html#retries

You can configure 2 properties in the connector config :

```
max.retries=30
retry.backoff.ms=10000
```

Here, it will retry 30 times with waiting 10 seconds between each try (=300 seconds = 5 minutes)

Comment: the correct link https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC sink connect shares the same parameters as the source connector. 
The following are use for connection attempt

```
connection.attempts
Maximum number of attempts to retrieve a valid JDBC connection.

Type: int
Default: 3
Importance: low

connection.backoff.ms
Backoff time in milliseconds between connection attempts.

Type: long
Default: 10000
Importance: low
```

ref: 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/source_config_options.html#database

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/v5.3.0-rc4/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/util/CachedConnectionProvider.java#L43